# number of elements surrounding an element in a matrix, matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, surround, thickness

I need to write a function that finds the "deepness" of a cell (row,col) in a matrix.

Given any nxm matrix say `mat = ones(6,6)` for example..

```
mat =

     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

The result would be:

```
thick =

     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     2     2     2     1
     1     2     3     3     2     1
     1     2     3     3     2     1
     1     2     2     2     2     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Where "1" is the least thickness possible, defining an edge cell. Each additional surrounding cell adds +1 thickness. NAN's would need to be handled as an "edge" if they are on a boundary... but I can build that in later I think.

Ideas? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

Removed my original edit, need to rethink my original problem. Basically I want to find the deepest cell in a matrix. The matrix does not have to be regular and can have holes. Normally this would be accomplished using a polygon and finding the diameter of the largest circle that fits inside that polygon, but I'm not sure how efficiently I could implement that in MATLAB. Hmmmm....

Comment: Ha, the bullseye matrix from Cody :)

Answer (score 1):

here's a 1-d hint:
given m as your matrix:

```
m=ones(1,6)
i=1:length(m);
depth(i<=length(m)/2)=i(i<=length(m)/2);
depth(i>length(m)/2)=length(m)-i(i>length(m)/2)+1
```

m =

```
 1     1     1     1     1     1
```

depth =

```
 1     2     3     3     2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build  a function around the following logic (presenting the pseudocode here ) :

```
depth(m):
   M = size(m,1);
   N = size(m,2);
   thick = zeros(M,N);
   for i=1:M
        for j = 1:N
            thick(i,j) = min(i,M-i+1,j,N-j+1);
   return thick;
```

Where `depth(m)` returns the depth of the `(i,j)` element in an `MxN` matrix `m` indexed from 1.